# Displaying 0 when output does not match

Tags: java

I cannot display 0 when my outputs doesn't match each other which leaves a blank. I tried adding this line of code

```
pract.get(base).append("0,");
```

which gives me this output:

```
a,0,0,0,1

b,1,0,0,0

c,0,1,0,0
```

I just want to have  1 column of numbers.

```
      if ( rs.getString("abc") != null )
           def = rs.getString("gtd1");

           String[] parts = def.split("<SPLIT>");

            for ( int i = 0 ; i <parts .length ; i ++ )
               {
                  if ( pract.containsKey(parts [i]) )
                  pract.get(gateNo[i]).put(abc, "1");
                  else
if ( rs.getString("abc") != null )
       def = rs.getString("gtd1");

       String[] parts = def.split("<SPLIT>");

        for ( int i = 0 ; i <parts .length ; i ++ )
           {
              if ( pract.containsKey(parts [i]) )
              pract.get(gateNo[i]).put(abc, "1");
           }
    }

   for ( int i = 0 ; i < type2.size(); i++)
   {            
       for ( String base: pract.keySet() )
       {
           if ( gates.get(base).containsKey(  type2.get(i)  ) )
               pract.get(base).append("1,");
       }

   }
               }
        }

       for ( int i = 0 ; i < type2.size(); i++)
       {            
           for ( String base: pract.keySet() )
           {
               if ( gates.get(base).containsKey(  type2.get(i)  ) )
                   pract.get(base).append("1,");
               else
                   pract.get(base).append("0,");
           }

       }
```

Current output is

```
a,

b,1

c,1
```

The output i'm trying to get is

```
a,0

b,1

c,1
```

Comment: Add an in the `else` block `pract.get(gateNo[i]).put(abc, "0"); `where you check if `pract` contains the key.

Comment: You can use a `found` boolean and at the end of the loop if `found==false` you write your 0.

Comment: @SubOptimal its not working :/

Comment: @justalazyguy Could you provide a working snippet which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @SubOptimal just updated the codes.

Comment: @justalazyguy I guess `rs` is a `ResultSet` from a database query. Could you also provide more information about `pract` and what it contains before the processing of one (ore more?) rows. And what do you expect it should contain after the processing. I belive you do not want us to provide a solution based only on our guesses. Isn't it?